# Android studio: Process 'command 'python'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, oculusgo

I have been using android studio to develop for an OculusGO. It has been working fine, but now suddenly my android studio project refuses to build, and I just get the error message:

```
Process 'command 'python'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I did not do anything for this error message to suddenly start appearing. What is causing this problem and how can I fix it? Android studio version 3.2.1.

edit:

the error happens in the build stage 'Execute buildSdkLibs'. Full error log:

```
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'python'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:389)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.exec(DefaultFileOperations.java:189)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.exec(DefaultProject.java:1087)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.exec(DefaultProject.java:1082)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$exec$6.call(Unknown Source)
    at BuildSDKLibs.buildSdkLibs(/home/jonathan/Downloads/ovr_sdk_mobile_1.18.0/VrApp.gradle:360)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: We need more related logs to determine what happened. It could be something incompatible with the new verssion

Comment: @jackz314 I added the full error log. Although I don't know what you mean "with the new version", I did not update Android Studio recently.

Comment: Update then and check.

Comment: updated to 3.4, still the same problem

Comment: I just reinstalled my whole android studio and sdk, and trying to run a sample project, still getting the same error

Comment: I have the same issue when just trying to build the VR samples (https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-mobile-sdk/). Have you found any solution? Spänger

Comment: @MisseMask Yes I found a solution, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**
Change the gradle wrapper version to 4.7 or higher, by changing the file `gradle-wrapper.properties` in `ovr_sdk_mobile_***/gradle/wrapper`

**Details**

When building a project that uses the Oculus VR Api, it runs VrApp.gradle, which in turn runs a python script. This python script fails, and this is where the error comes from. The python script that is run is `bin/scripts/ovrbuild_sklibs.py`, which in turn runs `ovrbuild.py`, which in turn seems to run a different gradle file. Anyway, the error output that is interesting for us is the `err` in the `call` function in `ovrbuild.py`. The print statement is swallowed by android studio, so either you would have to run gradle from the command line somehow (I guess, but I don't know gradle very well), but I just saved the error to file by editing the python script. The error message is

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

This seems to be a well known error, that comes from the fact that somewhere between java 9 and 11, the format of `java -version` changed (see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22487), and gradle was unable to detect it for a while. However, it was patched in version 4.7, so for me the solution was to change the gradle wrapper version to a higher version (NOT the gradle version in android studio, but the one specified in gradle-wrapper.properties). I have no idea why this error suddenly appeared for me, but probably my java version must somehow have updated without me noticing.

edit: as comments point out, change to 4.8 or higher, I wrote 4.7 because that is what they said in the online source, but perhaps it was not patched in 4.7000 but some other version 4.7xxx

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. For me, I had to use 4.8 or higher.

Comment: Interesting... I started hitting this error updating from SDK 1.23 to 1.24.0, and I'm seeing that the wrapper changed from 4.4 to 4.7; I guess I will try changing it back to 4.4 or up to 4.8...

Comment: Heads up, changing `gradle-wrapper.properties` to version `4.8` worked for me with `ovr_sdk_mobile_1.24.0.zip`. 